# Play Store doesn't accept my AppBundle with Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, google-play

I want to upload my Flutter AppBunble to PlayStore but I got this message from PlayStore:

[image]

And Here are AndroidManifest.xml codes:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="co...">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="... هروی">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="akhlaqmarefat.com" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="host"
                    android:pathPrefix="/book" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I run this command to generate AppBundle:

```
flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=~/Projects/Lajward/LibraryApp
```

**My System Info:**

Flutter 3.0.2

Dart 2.17.3

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

And also I tried all of the answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70684516/uploaded-an-apk-which-has-an-activity-activity-alias-service-or-broadcast-receiv), but still the same issue.

Please help me with what is wrong exactly here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unit testing, we found the problem was from this package `epub_viewer: ^0.2.5`, the AndroidManifest.xml of this package was empty:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.jideguru.epub_viewer">
</manifest>
```

and also doesn't have any activity or service, but this [solution work for me](https://github.com/JideGuru/epub_viewer/issues/123), by adding these lines of code to my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
    <activity
        android:name = "com.folioreader.ui.activity.SearchActivity"
        android:exported = "true"
        tools:node="merge" />
```

the PlayStore accepted my AppBundle.

Answer (score 2):

**Main Suggestion**: You have to set your `android:exported=true` for the activity.
For more details see here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported

**Suggestion 2**:
Also, if you are using packages which have native code and include an activity then you might also have to add android:exported flag there also.

**Suggestion 3(Workaround)**:
If possible you can change your target SDK version below the API level of Android12 to make it go away.

**Edit:**
If you are using third party packages then you might try checking if all your other packages come with support of Android 12. Try running `pub outdate` to see the packages which can be upgraded or manually check all the packages which you have:
To Check:
Go to your FlutterSDK Path and go to .pub-cache/hosted/
and look at the build.gradle file for each of the package you are using cause many packages might be having target sdk below 12 which might be causing the issue. Also try updating those packages.

Also, try without obfuscation it might solve your problem.

Comment: Did you read my code? Because I set `android:exported="true"` to MainActivity

Comment: Not in your activity but the third party packages that you have must also have any activity set the android:exported package. Also try using  the edit.

Comment: I set it in all package

Comment: Try without obfuscation, because it sometimes causes problems.(Just to see if it works).

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: And I try it without obfuscation like this `flutter build appbundle`, but doesn't work.

Comment: As a temporary fix you can just make your target sdk version lower than Android 12.

Comment: I did but I got this issue `Your project requires a higher compileSdkVersion.`

Comment: Usually compileSdk version and targetSdk versions both are changed simultaneously compileSdk means that you use the gradle specified in that android version to compile your app but target sdk version means that you have tested your app on that version. Usually we set both of them to the same version in `build.gradle` (app module)

Comment: The fix you are using is temporary. If your app is open source then you could give me a link to source code. Will be happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply open your native app as below
[image]

After opening that go through your android manifest file i seen that you have already added the exported="true" in mainactivity but after opening the manifest file see the error and suggestions in manifest

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work for me