# Getting error when trying to upload IONIC app on Google Play Store

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic4, google-play-console

When i try to updload the ionic app on google play store i get this error from play store:

*You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher.*

Here is my androidmanifest.xml file code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10006" android:versionName="1.0.6" package="io.givllyfilos.edhub" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.emailcomposer.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.emailcomposer.Provider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/emailcomposer_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.sharing.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/sharing_paths" />
        </provider>
        <amazon:enable-feature android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging" android:required="false" xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android" />
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler" />
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler$Receiver" android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="io.givllyfilos.edhub" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity android:label="Share" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" />
        <meta-data android:name="launchnavigator.GOOGLE_API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyAo-TVesQ37IzUMhCDkpEn6REyeLyFO6as" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.android.gm" />
        <package android:name="com.microsoft.office.outlook" />
        <package android:name="com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail" />
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="io.givllyfilos.edhub.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="io.givllyfilos.edhub.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploaded an APK which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intentfilter, but without 'android : exported' property set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70684516/uploaded-an-apk-which-has-an-activity-activity-alias-service-or-broadcast-rece)

Answer (score 0):

Clean the build and rebuild again.